# Minecraft 1.7.10 Forge These libraries failed to download

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have MC 1.7.10 and I wanted to download Forge. I tried so many Forge versions for 1.7.10, but when I run the installer, the download bar works for awhile, then it says: These libraries failed to download org.scala-lang

I checked the versions folder in my .minecraft and it shows the folders for the Forge profiles, but when I go to the launcher itself, there are no Forge profiles. Just the regular version names. I also checked the scala-library folder and it has the jar file scala-library 2.11.1

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Internet connection perhapes? They all download fine for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because tech support for modded Minecraft is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Re-launch the forge installer. Its common for forge to do that. Also, make sure that you have a internet connection. Hopefully that works for you.